# How to run gdb on an executable with arguments?

Tags: gdb

How can I run something like `gdb -e path/to/exe -ex 'run --argnamae argvalue'`?

Let's assume a recent version of gfb, within the past year or two.

Gdb runs and prints responses but not interactively.

Comment: "Of course i get the useless error 'ImportError: ... but that is par for the course." -- It is *not* par for the course. It indicates an installation problem. If you want to get rid of it, you should probably ask a separate question, and edit this one to remove references to ImportError.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a program with commandline arguments using GDB within a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121094/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-commandline-arguments-using-gdb-within-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you want `gdb --args path/to/exe command line arguments`

which will start gdb debugging `path/to/exe` pass three command line arguments to your exe `command`, `line`, and `arguments`, you can then interact with gdb before issuing the run command.

As for the `ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'` I believe this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062010/ubuntu-14-04-gcc-4-8-4-gdb-pretty-printing-doesnt-work-because-of-python-issu) which points to a bug report [here](http://osdir.com/ml/debian-gcc/2014-02/msg00061.html).

It appears some versions of GCC have a broken pretty printers python script, you might need to adjust the python `sys.path` with `(gdb) python sys.path.append("/usr/share/gcc-4.8/python")`, adjust the path to match whatever GCC version is actually present on your system.  You could probably add a command like this to your `.gdbinit` file to save typing it every time.

Comment: Good to know! But what about `gdb --args path/to/exe command line="can have whitespace in" arguments`? When running gdb is reporting `path/to/exe can't handle command-line argument containing whitespace`. Any solution for handling arguments with whitespaces?

Comment: That error only occurs (I think) when `set startup-with-shell 0` has been used.  Right now I don't see a work around (https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/infcmd.c;h=331fd8751b16a16d7b78b7e912eb25d3d3c1d69d;hb=HEAD#l360) other than not disabling `startup-with-shell`

Answer (score 9):

> How can I run something like ...

You can do this:

```
gdb path/to/exe -ex 'set args arg1 arg2 arg3'
```

Or use a shorthand notation for the above:

```
gdb --args path/to/exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass arguments from file,

try this

```
(gdb) run < the_file_contains_data
```

Comment: This is what I was after. I was normally using bash to cat a csv file into a C++ program vai CLI, thank you!!