# Cannot debug variable value in anjuta IDE using gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, ide, gdb, anjuta

I'm trying to debug local variables values of a C++ project using Anjuta IDE, but all I'm getting is `{...}` instead of the actual values. See for example the next picture and what happens with the `buf` and `buf1` variables (with all of them actually...):

[image]

I've looked into pretty printers, but that seems to be for more complex objects and structures. My variables are simply `std::string` and I guess they should be displaying their values without much more trouble.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I've moved from anjuta to Eclipse CDT, I think this had nothing to do with anjuta itself, but with a problem in gdb configuration due to a known bug that prevents pretty printers from working.

There seems to be a couple of workarounds. The one I've successfully tried is:

- Create a ~/.gdbinit file to be used when running gdb.
- Add `python sys.path.append("/usr/share/gcc-4.8/python");` to it

See [Ubuntu 14.04, gcc 4.8.4: gdb pretty printing doesn't work because of Python issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062010/ubuntu-14-04-gcc-4-8-4-gdb-pretty-printing-doesnt-work-because-of-python-issu/34580769) for more info.